# Identification of sequences of numbers which grow by one and get position

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I have a vector which partially entails sequences of numbers which **grow by one**, for example:

```
x<- c(1,2,3,5,4,2,40,41,2,9,4)
```

the sequences "1,2,3" and "40,41" are auch sequences. What I would like is to generate a vector per such sequence which entails the position of each element in the main vector (hier "x"). For the given examle it would be two vectors:

```
v1<-c(1,2,3) # for the sequence 1, 2 and 3 in x and
v2<-c(7,8)   # for the sequence 40 and 41 in x.
```

How could I accomplish it in R?

Comment: Please provide your input with valid R syntax. Pasting it into my R session results in an error.

Comment: Hi Roland, I removed the quotes. It is about x. But the vectors v1 and v2 are what I would like to get. I don't know how to get them with an R code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x<- c(1,2,3,5,4,2,40,41,2,9,4)
n1 <- which(c(0, diff(x))==1)
n2 <- n1-1
n <- sort(union(n1,n2))
split(n, cumsum(c(1,diff(n))!=1))
# $`0`
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $`1`
# [1] 7 8
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written that tool:   `cgwtools::seqle` . It's like `rle` but searches for sequences.

Comment: @JohnnyB like `rle`, `seqle` returns two vectors, one of which gives the starting value for each run and the other of which gives the length of the run.  So look for "length" values >1 and use them to grab the locations in your original vector.

Comment: @JohnnyB, that's a pity. It doesn't give you the answer up until the final line, but it provides you with a fine start!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I realize I formulated the question wrongly. I got my result using `seqle` as follows:

```
library("cgwtools")
x<- c(1,2,3,5,4,2,40,41,2,9,4)
v<-seqle(x,incr=1)$values
l<-seqle(x,incr=1)$lengths

erg<-list(rep(NA),length(v))
for(i in 1:length(v))
    erg[[i]]<-seq(v[i],l[i]+v[i]-1)
```